# Importing flat file which has changing column order using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file with header in the first row and data from 2 row.
I have build the SSIS package based on a sample file.
After some time the order of the columns in the file started changing.
like earlier its used be something like FirstName,LastName, Address1 etc
and Now its is LastName,FirstName,Address1 etc 
there are other columns which are similar issue.
Each time the order changes i had to remap. i thought of writing a script but the even the script need an input and also requires a remappig is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: Can't you make the import based on column name no location ?

Comment: Part 2 of the solution there - query your flat files like they were a table and column order issue is no longer a problem